# Should I ask for higher salary than the average for jobs with 50% travel?

Tags: salary, travel

The position is data scientist, and normally there is no travel in such positions. The position I applied to requires around 50% travel to areas with time zone +- 12hours. 
The costs of the travel are covered by the company totally.

Should I ask for more money for that? How much?
What else do I need to consider for this case also?

Update:
This question differs from others in many perspectives.
Here, there is a specific job that was not mentioned in other questions, which gives a room for extra discussion. Also, the travel percentage is job-dependent, i.e., it differs from job to job.

Comment: It might be if the travel is to different destinations and less frequent than 50 -70%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Comment: Do you have any idea *how* the company approaches travel? Do they provide paid downtime between flights to adjust to time zones? Do they giver *per diems*? Airport lounge access or business class options? Have you been able to talk to your direct manager or future peers about how they experience that travel?

Comment: Come on @gnat, there's a clear difference in scope with the general salary question. Not everything is a duplicate.

Comment: [This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21883/impact-of-100-travel-on-salary-expectations?rq=1) that popped up in the Related side-bar is actually a lot more relevant and this could even be a duplicate. I'm not sure if the distinction between 50% travel and 100% is ultimately relevant to what you should consider salary-wise.

Comment: Not a dupe and even if the question is somewhat close to another, isn't there "room" for both? Are you afraid that workplace will run out of disk space?

Comment: @teego1967 fear probably goes in opposite direction: folks dumping their answers into duplicates are afraid to directly compete with time-proven answers in an older dupe target

Comment: Would you accept less money (or current offer) if they remove travel from job profile? This will help understand how (un)important travel is for you. (both the adventure and the experience which comes with it).

Comment: @PagMax: You should make that an Answer!

Comment: "Should I" that's up to you isn't it? Also what status would you have ? full ride expat style (ie they provide house servants etc) or just expenses and you make all your own arrangements

Answer (score 9):

Things to consider

Where are you travelling to? If it's into a potentially dangerous or unstable, or even just expensive country that makes a big difference.

How often will you be travelling and what sort of accommodation will you get, again big difference between a tiny budget in a seedy hotel and more luxurious quarters.

Do you actually like travelling? The novelty value DOES wear off especially since it seems a lot of your time will be spent in transit.

How will it interfere with personal commitments? eg,. sports, wife, kids, chess club, dungeons and dragons Friday with the buddies.

Factor those in and if they don't balance out a bit then certainly ask for more if you think it warranted.

Comment: I worked at an Lebanese civil engineer in the 80 and for "problematic" countries that we would send people  to where paid a EHB (Extra Hazard Bonus) Angola was 70/80% from memory

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ask for more money for that?

It is a question of supply and demand so It depends: Does the Travel-requirement lessen or widen the pool of willing candidates?

If, in your case, we assume travel is mostly seen as a burden, it means there are less candidates so you are in a good position to request an above-average salary.

> How much?

As always, this is a bit of a gamble - the more you ask, the bigger the chances there is somebody else with a more compelling offer. So the question is, how much do you want/need this job?

> What else do I need to consider for this case also?

How much do you really have to give for this job? Does it actually pay enough to justify the away-time and the added stress? Can this better be compensated by more holidays or less weekly work time than by money? How will it further you career if you do this, maybe only for a limited time?